# dir command is running on path given in command + current path

Tags: c#, shell, cmd, directory

I am running a test to check if there are files of type *.exe in a certain folder.
I am sending the commands from one computer to another (if that's matter..)
my condition in the code is:

```
if (string.Contains("File Not Found"))
    test PASS
else
    test FAIL
```

(don't mind the syntax PASS\FAIL it's just the idea)
(when files not found with DIR command then this string will appear at the end of search)

the command sent is:

```
"dir " + PATH + " *.exe /s"
```

the problem is, in results I get all the subfiles in the wanted directory, but also the command runs on the current folder (which can be anything, I can't change that and it can change from time to time and obviously I don't want this folder to effect on the result of the PATH I searched in).

the code written in C#, the commands themselves run on cmd.
what can be the problem?

the results look like this:

```
 Directory of C:\Windows\Temp  //PATH = C:\Windows\Temp

12/26/2019  04:26 PM    <DIR>          .
12/26/2019  04:26 PM    <DIR>          ..

 0 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\.............

09/03/2019  08:11 PM             8,704 NAME.exe
.
.
.
18 File(s)      2,141,696 bytes
```

so my test fails when it shouldn't.
how can I resolve that?

Comment: `but also the command runs on the current folder` That doesn't sound right. Can you add the code where you run the `dir` command? Also, is there a reason why you are not using C#'s [directory API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: could you give an example about the C#'s directory API? maybe I could use it...  
the code is:  

`ReturnValue ret;
string retValue;  
ret = DUT.Shell.Execute("dir " + TempPath + " *.exe /s");  
retValue = ret.ToString();  
TestContext.Log.ResultInfo(retValue); // this command returns what I printed in the question  `
  
I'm using some libraries from work... the DUT sending the command the second computer and the ReturnValue just holds what was returned from the command..

Comment: ohh yes there is a reason I don't use the c#s library for that... I have to run these commands on cmd...

Comment: So the `dir` command is running on a remote PC and that is being done with some in-house library. Maybe the issue is with that API. Also, what is `TempPath`? You can specify more than one path to the `dir` command. For example: `dir C:Windows\Temp;. /s` will produce the given results.

Comment: TempPath is the string that holds the wanted path to run the dir command on.(I checked it really holds the relevant path... )
I need to run it only on this path, that would be enough.
so you say there is no way the dir command would act like that? it should run only on the path given in the command, no matter what is the current directory the cmd on...?

Comment: AFAIK, the only way to get the `dir` command to produce those results is by specifying 2 paths: `dir C:Windows\Temp;. /s`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"dir " + PATH + " *.exe /s"
                 ^--- this space is your problem.
```

You execute `dir` with two parameters, so it lists all files matching the first string (`PATH`), then all files matching the second string (`*.exe` from the current working folder). You can verify in the command prompt with `dir c:\windows *.*` vs. `dir c:\windows\*.*` So remove the space.

Note: it's safer to also put quotes around the string (in case there are intended spaces (like in `Program Files`): `dir "c:\program files\*"`. (I don't know how to do that in `C#`, but if you know about `C#`, it should be easy)

Comment: Nice catch. I didn't notice the space. Also, probably a good use case for [`Path.Combine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple commands on the same line

"cd " + PATH + " && dir *.exe /s /b"